# Exception Could not find generator for route flutter

Tags: flutter, routes

I am new to flutter can any one help me solve this i am trying this from a while that some exception is coming when i want to switch the route my 
Main code:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  initialRoute:'/home',
  routes: {
    '/':(context) => Loading(),
    '/home':(context) => Home(),
    '/loc':(context) => ChooseLocation(),
}
));
```

my home page code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/loc');
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.edit_location),
                label: Text('Edit Location'))
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

got error like this

```
Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/loc", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
```

can someone help me!

Comment: I couldn't regenerate your error... It worked fine when i tried your code. Please check if you imported everything correctly.

Comment: You might have pressed 'Hot Reload' instead of 'Hot Restart' after adding ```'/loc':(context) => ChooseLocation(),``` into main.dart

Comment: yeah thank you i got it

Answer (score 2):

'Hot Restart' solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue we should try using flutter hot restart